# Draw lines between divs using css border

Tags: jquery, css, border, line, connection

This below is a "jQuery plugin that adds stylable connecting lines using CSS border among block elements of your page, which is good for web based mind map or project flow."

I was trying to use it but when I do, it connects every box to every box.  Can't I just connect one to another or one to two others.

This is what I get.  Please check out the link below.

[image: Image of my tree]

http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Add-Connecting-Lines-Between-Block-Elements-Connections.html

Code I'm using:

```
    <table>
    <td/>
    <td/>
<th>example
    <tr>
    <td/>
    <th>example</th>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <th>example</th>
    </tr>
<th>example</th>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <td/>   
    <td/>
    <th>example</th>
<tr>
    <td/>
    <td/>
<th>example</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

my full code is:

```html
<!doctype html>

<style>
 th {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
 }
 connection {
  border: 7px solid black;
  border-radius: 31px;
 }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.connections.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('th').connections();
 });
</script>

<table>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <th>example
        <tr>
            <td/>
        <th>example</th>
<td/>
<td/>
<th>example</th>
</tr>
<th>example</th>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>   
<td/>
<th class="class1">example</th>
<tr>
<td/>
<td/>
<th class="class1">example</th>
</tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "/index.html"
</script>
```

I don't exactly get what I'm supposed to add?

Solution: 
as @Brian suggested I used `$('.class1').connections();` and added as much as I needed class2, class3, class4, ect. Then in th class I put `class="class1 class6"` which would draw a line to any other class1 and class6.

[image: example result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, you should be able to do this:

```
<table>
    <td/>
    <td/>
    <th>example
        <tr>
            <td/>
        <th>example</th>
<td/>
<td/>
<th>example</th>
</tr>
<th>example</th>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>   
<td/>
<th class="class1">example</th>
<tr>
<td/>
<td/>
<th class="class1">example</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

And then this:

$('.class1').connections();

If you call it with the code they listed, it is applying the css to all th tags so it would connect every box.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't run (probably because jquery.connections.js isn't actually on stackoverflow, you need a cdn) but this line $('th').connections(); is connecting every th to every other th,  You want to add a class or something selectable to the boxes you want selected and call it that way, such as my example: $('.class1').connections();

Comment: so just add `$('class1').connections();` after `$('th').connections();` ? Thanks @Brian  it won't change anything

Comment: No, you need to replace $('th').connections(); and update the html accordingly for your use case... do you understand what $('th') is doing?

Comment: yes I understand it's just I already tried changing a few things. And I already have the html accordingly right?  If I change `th` to `class1` all the lines disappear the ones marked `class="class1"` don't appear.  Thanks @Brian

Comment: $('class1') is illegal syntax, it has to be $('.class1')... you'll also need to remove the old reference to th or it will continue to place those.

Comment: On the demo it shows you could style the line.  Where would I put the styles? in the `<style>`?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which element the connection should go to using

```
$('th').connections({ to: '.class1' }); or 
$('.child').connections({ to: '.class1' });
```

You will then need to structure your parent->child relationships using classes on your 'th' elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have one messy code. I believe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
<!doctype html>

<style>
    .block {
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    connection {
        border: 7px solid black;
        border-radius: 31px;
        z-index: -999;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.connections.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#1').connections({
          to: '#5',
        });
        $('#4').connections({
          to: '#3',
        });
        $('#2').connections({
          to: '#6',
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="1" class="block">example</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id="2" class="block">example</td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="3" class="block">example</td>
        <td></td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="4" class="block">example</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>   
        <td id="5" class="block">example</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="6" class="block">example</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: example]

Edit:
The reason your code messed up is because you triggered the connections function to all of the 'th' elements. You can assign ids to each elements instead and attach options when calling (element).connections({ }); if you want it to connect individually.

Comment: Thanks leonardykris , but @Brian already helped me with a solution that better fits me. Thanks, God Bless You.

Comment: Alright, do make sure that you restructure your code too. The structure is a bit off right now with the 'th' and 'tr' elements being thrown here and there